# Failed to find "GLESv2" when compiling OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I'm having trouble compiling opencv 2.4.7 with cmake, I get a `Failed to find "GLESv2"` error:

```
(hal)pi@raspberrypi ~/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.7/build $ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 46 (406)

-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/libIlmImf.so
CMake Error at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:31 (message):
  Failed to find "GLESv2" in "/opt/vc/lib".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:64 (_qt5gui_find_extra_libs)
  /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:137 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:19 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:421 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

However, I see `libGLESv2.so` in the `/opt/vc/lib` directory:

```
(hal)pi@raspberrypi ~/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.7/build $ cd /opt/vc/lib
(hal)pi@raspberrypi /opt/vc/lib $ ls
libbcm_host.so   libEGL.so        libGLESv1_CM.so  libGLESv2_static.a  libkhrn_static.a  libmmal.so       libmmal_vc_client.so  libOpenVG.so        libvchiq_arm.so  libvcos.so            libwayland-egl.so
libdebug_sym.so  libEGL_static.a  libGLESv2.so     libkhrn_client.a    libmmal_core.so   libmmal_util.so  libopenmaxil.so       libvcfiled_check.a  libvchostif.a    libvmcs_rpc_client.a  libWFC.so
```

I'm not sure what's going on if the GLESv2 library file seems to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run the Cmake command by editing the
`/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake`
file and adding

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/vc/lib)
set(_qt5gui_OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR /opt/vc/include)
```

at the start of the file.